# Identify that Android device supports EAP-SIM for WiFi authentication programatically

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, wifi

Currently there are two types of Android devices available in the market. Some devices support EAP-SIM authentication, while other does not. How can I identify programmatically whether my device support EAP-SIM authentication or not?

Comment: Just curious, have you manage to create a EAP-SIM profile on a device that supports this feature?

Comment: @jannej I haven't tried for eap-sim but i have created eap-tls,eap-ttls and eap-peap profile on a device supporting respective functionality

Answer (score 2):

To implement EAP-SIM feature, it requires patched `wpa_supplicant` and API to access APDU channel.

Since the AOSP did not have EAP-SIM support, there are different implementations on the market. It's hard to identify from `wpa_supplicant`, but we can check the APIs or service to guess if the device has smart card support or not.

1. Check `com.android.internal.telephony.RILConstants` or `com.android.internal.telephony.CommandsInterface`. [Git at Google](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/40d1d394302d83eb56f66cf08daecc612c97cd28%5E!/)
2. Check if there is `android.uid.smartcard` system service. (Sony)