# How to detect if device support EAP-SIM

Tags: java, android

For my application, I need to detect if my device support EAP-SIM. 
Anyone knows if this is possible or not?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892040/how-can-we-identify-programatically-that-android-device-suports-eap-sim-for-wifi) useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally i get the solution for my problem:

```
public static boolean isEAPSIMSupported() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if("org.simalliance.openmobileapi.service.SmartcardService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            Log.i(WifiHelper.class, "EAP-SIM Supported");
            return true;
        }
    }
    Log.i(WifiHelper.class, "EAP-SIM not Supported");
    return false; 
}
```